# Session variables disappear for some users (drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, session

I have this problem in my site that haunts me for months. I keep getting around it, but now I seem not to be able to find such a way, so I figured why not tackle the root problem?

My root problem is that sometimes (not always) session data disappears for some of my users. I know most of them for sure have cookies enabled. I thought maybe it's a session expiry thing, but I don't think that's it. I set the expiration for very long, plus the amount of users that their session gets erased is just too damn high...

I'm using drupal 6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any code? It would help if we had something to work with.

Comment: code? 
<?php echo $_SESSION['notworking'];?>   displays nothing

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of the pages that use sessions?

Comment: @MosheShaham What do you mean "the session daya disapear"?  The user gets logged out?  How do you know?  How long did you set the session expiration for?  How did you set the session expiration to be long?  Please answer those question so I can try to help you with drupal.

Comment: @roychr no, the user doesn't gets logged off. the data that i stored in a certain page gets erased by the time the user gets to another page. I know because I check, and i have logs. I set the expiration for 55 hours or so in settings.php

Comment: Does your session data persist in the database? Do a direct `SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE uid = $UID` on the database when you lose data you expect to have to see what's happening. Try disabling `sess_gc()` in `session.inc` (i.e. set it to just `return TRUE;` without doing anything) and see if that helps. If so it's being killed by garbage collection, if not the problem is elsewhere. This will fill your sessions table rapidly though!

Comment: Checked in the database - the data disappeared from there as well. changed sess_gc, i'll wait 24 hours to see if the problem persist

Comment: changed session.inc, still getting the bug

Comment: **Suggestion:** You need to start to debug that. Trace the cases where this happens. You need to stop guessing for that. Asking here is fine, but don't expect too much practically useful suggestions, because everybody here needs to guess as well but you need to get away from guessing.

Comment: Just a thought but the site doesn't switch between 2 urls or similar? This could cause the session to disappear

Answer (score 4):

Few things, that you might want to check

1. How are your session garbage collector configured? Please verify PHP settings: session.gc_maxlifetime, session.gc_divisor, session.session.gc_probability. It's only a guess, but maybe GC is deleting your data.
2. Does data disappears from sessions table? If you use default session handler for Drupal, data of $_SESSION table is stored at session column of sessions table at serialized form.
3. If data perishes from database, and if you are able to repeat problem on your development server, you can also enable queries logging for your database (at mysql server configuration, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html for more details). With devel module enabled, you can decorate (devel module settings) your queries with comment including info about function executing query. This may help you to find problem. **DONT TRY ON production environment**
4. Sometimes problem can be caused by one of enabled modules, which cripples your $_SESSION table. Try to find all $_SESSION occurences at your enabled modules code, especialy at write context. Some regular expression will help at this task.

Comment: +1 - My money is on the GC. People rarely realise that if you increase the session lifetime, you also need to modify the GC session max life time.

Comment: tried setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 2 million, doesn't solve it.

Comment: What about point 2)? Did you verified how sessions table behave for users with reported problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ob_start()` and `session_start();` at the top of your script.

Comment: it's a drupal site. session variables are stored in general. but sometimes they disappear

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here, bit I think this might be your problem/solution:

Short answer: try setting session.cookie_lifetime in sites/default/settings.php to 0.

Long answer: the session depends on the session data on the server **and** the PHP session cookie on the client. If you set the session cookie lifetime too low (Drupal default is 23 days, so normally not a problem), the session might effectively be 'destroyed' on the client side (by the browser deleting the cookie, because it expired).

I had run into this problem at one time because I changed the Drupal session cookie lifetime from 23 days to something lower that seemed more 'appropriate' in an attempt to limit login duration for security reasons. But lowering the session cookie lifetime is not the solution. The best way to do this is to limit the session duration on the server side. You can do this by setting session.gc_maxlifetime (also in Drupal settings) to something like 7200 (for 2 hours). You then only need to make sure that session garbage collection is run often enough, so that sessions reliably end after 2 hours.

Then, to avoid problems with cookies being destroyed client-side, you can set session.cookie_lifetime to 0. This will make sure that, as long as the user is on the website, he will only be logged out if he stays inactive for longer than session.gc_maxlifetime. And on top of that it will also LOG THE USER OUT when he CLOSES his BROWSER. Which is not done by Drupal by default!!

ESSENTIAL UPDATE: Why is it a good idea to set cookie lifetime to 0? Because otherwise THE SERVER sets the DATE/TIME at which the client needs tot EXPIRE the cookie.
So what, you might say? Well, consider this situation: if the CLIENT HAS IT'S CLOCK SET WRONG (yes, it does happen, even when most computers update their time via NTP, some don't)!! It might expire the cookie much sooner then you think, EVEN UPON ARRIVAL.
This was the exact problem I had to debug once...

So try cookie lifetime 0 at least ONCE if you run into strange session problems :)

Comment: i don't understand. you're saying not set the cookie lifetime too low but to set it to 0? i didn't get it. right now it's set to 2 million. i prefer not to log users out when they close the browser

Comment: By too low I meant too low in time, i.e. don't set the time span too low. 0 == infinity or when browser closes. But I just noticed I forgot to mention something essential, I will update my post.

Comment: Please read the update about client clock setting. This might be your problem (or server clock setting for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with session save path

Please create a folder of name  (chmod 777   MUST) in your root directory i.e. where the .php is placed and place this code

```
if(!is_writable(session_save_path())){
    session_save_path(dirname(__FILE__)."/<xyz>");
}
```

Before starting the session.

And one more thing this happens when your session setting is on using files instead of memory.

Comment: i didn't really understand. how should I name the dir? and why should this work?

Comment: listen bud, i had under gone this error a while ago and this helped me to remove this error. now if you place this code in index.php then you have create a folder <xyz> inside the folder where your index.php is placed  to which it is pointing and must make it writable by the script to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, the reason being the famous www.

The site was enabled to be accessed through both www.example.com and example.com, which worked fine until the user hit a link which was hardcoded with the oposit domainname. Then he switched domain/subdomain and apache/php created a new session for the user on the "new" domain. It was in particular annoying when people were returning from payment.

Solution in our case was to always force users to use only example.com and either disable or redirect all requests to www.example.com directly to example.com. This way you never get sessions on both.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about a session_regenerate_id() problem of Drupal with some specific PHP version. Could you try to disable this feature and test it?

Comment: You can comment out the line "session_regenerate_id();" in the user.module. This problem was reported if the PHP version is 4.1 or 4.4. Which PHP version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I am following up on this post because it appears none of the answers solved the problem. I had a similar problem in D7 (and mod_fcgi) and therefore found this thread, the effect is not restricted to Drupal 6, the temporary storage service in Drupal 8 might alleviate this.

In brief, I would consider a race condition as the root cause. Websites built using Drupal and other frameworks involving Ajax can become complex beasts, with concurrent access to the session variables. I would first look for long-running requests using e.g. firefox-developer edition, a traffic analyzer, etc. Such could be introduced for example in blocks or other structure on the site, any of which might access $_SESSION. Subsequently, turn off as many blocks and menus as possible, until the problem disappears.

In addition, you could add some debug output to `includes/session.inc` in functions `drupal_session_start()` and `drupal_session_commit()`. The output should contain the process ids of server processes. Look for commits that occur long after the main content is displayed.

### Hypothesis on what might be going on

A long-running request overwrites session variables with an old state. This is partly due to how session variables are managed in Drupal. By default, session data is stored in the session column of the sessions table as a single serialized string representation of the data. In principle, reading and writing session variables should be an atomic action, but that is not easy to enforce. The code below is from session.inc and handles the writing of the session data. It uses a timestamp to and an is_changed flag to delay writing efficiently. One could also say, that sessions are not thread-safe. Also, it uses SQL MERGE statements, but this is not able to merge serialized variables; in effect, the latest written state is the winning state.

```php
    // For performance reasons, do not update the sessions table, unless
    // $_SESSION has changed or more than 180 has passed since the last update.
    if ($is_changed || !isset($user->timestamp) || REQUEST_TIME - $user->timestamp > variable_get('session_write_interval', 180)) {
      // Either ssid or sid or both will be added from $key below.
      $fields = array(
        'uid' => $user->uid,
        'cache' => isset($user->cache) ? $user->cache : 0,
        'hostname' => ip_address(),
        'session' => $value,
        'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
      );

    ...

    db_merge('sessions')
    ->key($key)
    ->fields($fields)
    ->execute();
```

Imagine the following scenario:

Main site content is a module that displays a button and a counter. The counter is stored in $_SESSION['counter'] and incremented by clicking a button. The button has an Ajax callback that does effectively the following

```php
function counter_increment(){
   if (!drupal_session_started()) {
        // Must initialize sessions for anonymous users.
        drupal_session_start();
   }
   $_SESSION['counter'] = (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) ? $_SESSION['counter']++ : 0;
   drupal_session_commit();
   ...
}
```

In a block in the site footer, there is a block loading session data that stalls for whatever reason.

```php
function do_nothing(){
   if (!drupal_session_started()) {
        // Must initialize sessions for anonymous users.
        drupal_session_start();
   }
   $otherdata = $_SESSION['otherdata'];
   // do something that takes a long time and eventually is finished or fails, like starting a site search:
  wait(200); // might work, request is now older than write delay (default 180)
  $_SESSION['otherdata'] = $otherdata; // session is updated now, too, possibly not necessary
  return TRUE;
 }
```

So once the content is loaded, the footer block calls do_nothing which than hangs for >180 seconds. In the meantime, the user increments the counter using the callback, but once do_nothing finishes, the whole session content will be replaced with the session content of the do_nothing request, thereby losing $_SESSION['counter'];