# What magical thing could be killing my Drupal session and anywhere from 15-45 minutes of activity?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using a standard Drupal install hosted on a LAMP stack. 
My settings.php has the following set:

```
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
```

my php.ini file has:

```
session.gc_probability = 1


session.gc_divisor = 1000


session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Also I have checked that the safe mode is off so that my settings.php file is able to override main php.ini variables.  Also since the person can get log out at 15 minutes, it is making me wonder whether php.ini has anything to do with it anyways. I have combed through my code and it seems to work fine on my local host however on server it is having issues. Where else can i possibly check?????

Comment: try adding the php tag maybe you might get some ideas from there

Comment: just a suggestion. Any module or JS for any reason modifies cookies?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972571/session-variables-disappear-for-some-users-drupal ?

Answer (score 0):

Narrow done your problem. Is the cookie expiration being set wrong? Or is it still being sent but no longer matching up with a valid session? My guess is it's a problem in drupal.